Get Data from one to another Workbook with condition
I have a problem with getting the data from other workbooks to the master file. So, In master file there is Working Hours sheet with five columns (country-filled, plant-filled, month-filled, week-filled, working hours-empty). I need to get working hours from other workbooks. Other Workbooks are stored in one folder.
I open each workbook and look for proper worksheet and then for proper week no. On the end I need to copy the data from other workbooks only if they meet the criteria (in master file I look for proper row (plant + month + week) and then I need to do the same in other workbooks. If both criteria's are the same then it working hours should be copied to master file - but only for this one row.
My code works correct by only for week = 1. If I change it to 2,3 or whatever then it does not copy anything.
Sub GetData()

    ' Deklaracja zmiennych
    Dim path As String
    Dim masterFile As String
    Dim monthNo As Integer
    Dim weekNo As Integer
    Dim plantList As Collection
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim workingHours As Double
    Dim foundRow As Range
    Dim plantName As String

    ' Uzupelniam kolekcje
    Set plantList = New Collection

    ' Dodanie nazw zakladów do kolekcji
    plantList.Add "Warszawa"
    plantList.Add "Czestochowa"
    plantList.Add "Zabrze"
    plantList.Add "Wroclaw"
    plantList.Add "Rzeszow"
    plantList.Add "Liberec"
    plantList.Add "Brno"
    plantList.Add "Krnov"
    plantList.Add "Prague"
    plantList.Add "Izmir"
    plantList.Add "Izmir (2)"
    plantList.Add "Bursa"
    plantList.Add "Gebze"
    plantList.Add "Jinan"
    plantList.Add "Kunshan"
    plantList.Add "Taicang"
    plantList.Add "Wuxi"
    plantList.Add "Jiaxing"
    plantList.Add "Vlkanova"
    plantList.Add "Budapest"
    plantList.Add "Brasov"

    ' Przypisanie sciezki do folderu
    path = "..."
    masterFile = "..." ' Nazwa pliku master
    
    ' Numer miesiaca i tygodnia
    monthNo = 10
    weekNo = 2
    
    ' Otwórz plik glówny
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(masterFile)
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Working hours") ' Zakladam, ze dane beda w arkuszu "Working hours"

    ' Przeszukaj pliki w folderze
    fileName = Dir(path & "*.xlsm")

    ' Petla przez wszystkie pliki w folderze
    Do While fileName <> ""
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & fileName)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        ' Petla przez wszystkie arkusze w pliku
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            ' Sprawdz, czy nazwa arkusza znajduje sie w kolekcji
            For Each item In plantList
                If ws.Name = item Then
                    plantName = ws.Name ' Zapisz nazwe zakladu (arkusza)
                    
                    ' Petla przez komórki w zakresie B33:B38
                    For Each cell In ws.Range("B33:B38")
                        ' Jesli wartosc komórki jest równa weekNo
                        If cell.Value = weekNo Then
                            ' Pobierz wartosc z kolumny H w tym samym wierszu
                            workingHours = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value + cell.Offset(0, 8).Value + cell.Offset(0, 10).Value + cell.Offset(0, 12).Value + cell.Offset(0, 14).Value + cell.Offset(0, 16).Value + cell.Offset(0, 18).Value
                            
                            ' Szukaj odpowiedniego miejsca w masterFile
                            Set foundRow = Nothing
                            Set foundRow = ws2.Range("B:B").Find(What:=plantName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                            
                            If Not foundRow Is Nothing Then
                                ' Sprawdz, czy miesiac i tydzien pasuja
                                If foundRow.Offset(0, 1).Value = monthNo And foundRow.Offset(0, 2).Value = weekNo Then
                                    ' Wstaw working hours do kolumny E w odpowiednim wierszu
                                    foundRow.Offset(0, 3).Value = workingHours
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next cell
                    
                End If
            Next item
        Next ws
        
        ' Zapisz i zamknij plik
        wb.Save
        wb.Close False
        
        ' Przejdz do kolejnego pliku
        fileName = Dir
        
    Loop
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' Wyswietl komunikat o zakonczeniu
    MsgBox "Job done!"

End Sub


You are currently always checking the column C (column B plus offset 1) for the month. The layout of your data is not clear (you should provide a screenshot or a table), but you need to find a formula to calculate the correct column for the month or you need to loop over all columns to find it.

@FunThomas I can't agree with you. First I'm focus on plant (column B) next I check column C and D with month & week. Here all is ok if it wouldn't be then it would not work for week 1. Table I described, no need to add, thanks.

"Table I described, no need to add" - ok, I'm out, I don't understand how your data looks like. If your code works only for one month, then obviously something is different for the other monthes. If data of different monthes are next to each other, you are using the wrong columns. If data of of different monthes is in different rows, probably you are looking at the wrong row foundRow - but I don't want to guess here. You should use the debugger to check where your code fails to find the data for month 10.

Create an anonymised version if you must, but you really need to include a sample table if you want help. Also, your description of the table doesn't really make sense (to me at least) - sheet with three five columns (country, plant, month, week) - should that be 3 sets of five columns? 3 rows by 5 columns? Also - you only list 4 fields?

@CLR I edited table description.

For me seems that, You need a loop to iterate through ws2.Columns("B") for all the plantname occurences to find the corresponding month and week. Presently it checks only the first row with the appropriate plantname

As Black cat said you need continue the search of column B using FindNext
    Set foundRow = Nothing
    Set foundRow = ws2.Range("B:B").Find(What:=plantName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not foundRow Is Nothing Then
        firstAddr = foundRow.Address
        
        Do
            ' Sprawdz, czy miesiac i tydzien pasuja
            If foundRow.Offset(0, 1).Value = monthNo And foundRow.Offset(0, 2).Value = weekNo Then
                ' Wstaw working hours do kolumny E w odpowiednim wierszu
                foundRow.Offset(0, 3).Value = workingHours
            End If
            Set foundRow = ws2.Range("B:B").FindNext(foundRow)
           
        Loop While foundRow.Address <> firstAddr
        
    End If
 

